# docker system prune -a doesn't clean space, but troubleshoot option does

Tags: docker, disk

I've been doing some tests with docker recently (in Linux), and eventually I thought I would like to do a clean up, so I found about the docker system prune command, and after running it I got this `Total reclaimed space: 783MB` .

But, after running the Disk Usage Analyzer I found that my .docker folder in Home is taking the same size, even after pulling the images and using prune again (with the -a flag also) the folder (and more specifically Docker.raw) still takes 3,1 GB.

So, I've tried using the Clean/Purge data option in the troubleshoot section of Docker Desktop, and it indeed worked, taking my folder again to 2,7 GB.

How could I achieve the same results using the terminal, as it's more practical? I know that the size is difference is now minimal, but I don't think the command will work even with a bigger file size. Thanks.

Comment: Next time, run a `docker system df` in order to identify where the data are. Originally `docker system prune --all --volumes` would clean everything, but, since recently, the system prune command won't delete named volumes anymore, so you might want to run a `docker volume prune --all` first. And if you want to clear everything, a `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` in order to kill all running container prior to all of this.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for the quick answer. I've tried these just to see, but I think the Docker Desktop "Clean/Purge Data" option is just more aggressive, maybe it removes more than just the images? These are the only thing I was trying to delete.

Comment: Yes, purge for the daemon should have deleted everything, images, containers, build caches, volumes, networks.